# In MongoDB Filter Builders for C#, is there any way to filter comparing multiple fields?

Tags: c#, database, mongodb

I am using Builders.Filter to filter MongoDB document in c#.

And I do simple filters for one fields criteria such as 'name=abc', and 'age>18', etc.

```
 
    ... ...
    var doc = db.GetCollection("student_document");
    var filterBuilder = Builders.Filter;
    var filter = filterBuilder.Eq("name", "abc") & filterBuilder.Gte("age", 18);
    var result = doc.Find(filter);
    ...
```

This works well.

However I am failing in filtering the value of mixed multiple fields.

Let's say Student document like this.

```
 
    public class Student
    {
        string name;
        int age;
        int entrance;
        List scores;
    }
```

I'd like to build filter for this criteria:

1st, (age*3 + entrance/2) > 0

2nd, (Sum of scores + entrance*3) > 100,

This is far and random example, but, any way to build this filer?

I think 'projection' will be the solution, but no idea how to use it.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried for the above criteria.

Comment: really no idea how to do...I only know one field filter and showed it in question